# Function parameters not being validated

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a simple calculator function in python where the function signature can take more than 2 nos, default operation will be ADD and default output format would be float.

```
def calculator(operation=ADD,output=float,*args):
```

Basically the function should apply the operation to the first two numbers, and then apply it again to the result and the next number, and so on. For example, if the numbers are 6, 4, 9 and 1 and the operation is subtraction the function should return 6 - 4 - 9 - 1.

However when I call the function with:

```
calculator(1,2,3,4,operation=ADD,output=float)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: calculator() got multiple values for argument 'operation'
```

Can someone please tell me how should i invoke this function with right set of parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Put `*args` first. It's interpreting your integers as values for `operation`, which is expecting a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function:

```
def calculator(operation, output, *args):
    pass
```

And you can use it with:

```
calculator('ADD', 'float', 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Your arguments are positional, so if you call:

```
calculator(1,2,3,4,operation=ADD,output=float)
```

You are actually saying that operation=1 and output=2, that´s why the interpreter complains about passing the value twice.

Answer (score 0):

when you call your function

```
def calculator(operation=ADD, output=float, *args):
    ...
```

like  `calculator(1,2,3,4,operation=ADD,output=float)` the argument are assigned first by position `1,2,3,4` and then by key-word `operation=ADD, output=float` so you get that *operation*=1, *ouput*=2 and *args* get the rest (3,4), then it try to assign the key-word arguments but it turn out that *operation* was already assigned hence the error.

So with your current definition call it as `calculator(ADD,float,1,2,3,4)` or change the definition to

```
def calculator(*args, operation=ADD, output=float):
    ...
```

this way *operation* and *output* are key-word only arguments and you can call it as before `calculator(1,2,3,4,operation=ADD,output=float)`.

But this syntax is python 3 only, to do the same in python 2 you need to do

```
def calculator(*args, **kwarg):
    operation = kwarg.get("operation",ADD)
    output = kwarg.get("output",float)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use args, kwargs for this. A good tutorial for this is given here. https://www.unixmen.com/introduction-python-args-kwargs-beginners-part-1/

```
>>> def calculator(*args, **kwargs):
...     for a in args:
...         print(a)
...     for k, v in kwargs.items():
...         print("%s := %s" % (k, v))
...
>>> calculator(1,2,3, op=add, ouput=float)
1
2
3
ouput := <class 'float'>
op := <built-in function add>
```